# Multiple request PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to do two GET request simultaneously with [this library](https://requests.ryanmccue.info/)

The API is from Woocommerce, and I have the API keys for authentication.

When I do a single request this works

```
<?php
include('requests/library/Requests.php');
Requests::register_autoloader();

$options1 = array(
    'auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic(array('user', 'password'))
);
$request_1 = Requests::get('https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders', array(), $options1);

var_dump($request_1->body);
```

Now I have to do two request simultaneously ($request_1 + $request_2),
what is the better way to use **Requests::request_multiple**?

Comment: Did you try to get support from the library authot? https://requests.ryanmccue.info/support/